# In Meteor, how to set a reactive dependency on a subpart of a template data context?

Tags: meteor

Consider the following code :

```
Template.fullDoc.rendered = function()  {

    // Get triggered whenever the selected document id changes
    this.autorun(function() {

        var docId = isolateValue(function() {
            return Template.currentData().selectedDoc._id; 
        });
        ...

    });

}
```

**This code doesn't work**. Inside `isolateValue()`, `Template.currentData()` sometimes triggers an exception: `Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: There is no current view` (this corresponds to the fact that `Template.instance()` returns `null`).

So how do you set a reactive dependency on a subpart of a template data context?

Comment: What is `isolateValue`?

Comment: isolateValue() is a function from this package: https://github.com/awwx/meteor-isolate-value

Comment: That package is old. Meteor evolved and is not rerendering whole template any more.

Comment: Why you are using isolateValue function ? Which version of meteor you are using ?

Comment: I use the latest Meteor version. I heavily rely on isolateValue to optimize reactivity perofrmances. But it seems it does not handle Template.xxxx() properly, so I will have to use the solution below. I would prefer isolateValue to be fixed, though, as it allows for more concise and self-explained code. I will post an issue in their repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could recreate the `isolateValue` behaviour in a way which doesn't cause `Template.instance()` to get set to `null` sometimes.

```
$ meteor add reactive-var
```

```js
Template.fullDoc.rendered = function () {
    var docIdVar = new ReactiveVar();
    this.autorun(function () {
        docIdVar.set(Template.currentData().selectedDoc._id);
    });
    this.autorun(function () {
        var docId = docIdVar.get();
        // ...
    });
}
```

This makes use of the fact that setting a `ReactiveVar` to the same value it already has will not trigger an invalidation. (By default this only works for primitives; for objects you'll need to pass a custom `equalsFunc` when you construct the `ReactiveVar`. If `_id` is a string, you're fine. If it's `ObjectID` you probably aren't.)

Comment: Thanks. It works, indeed.Do you know what is wrong in isolateValue()? I find it significantly less verbose...

Comment: `isolateValue` calls your function in a regular `Tracker.autorun` (back then it was called `Deps.autorun`), not a `templateInstance.autorun`. The value of `Template.instance` is normally lost in autoruns, like all asynchronous callbacks. `templateInstance.autorun` goes out of its way to preserve it.

Comment: Thanks dude! you saved me a lot of reasearch!